# How to call a testng class multiple time in Java

Tags: java, testng

I want to use TestNG for my auto test tool for generate report for all test while execute test as below.

```
for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
    ITestNGListener tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
    TestNG testng = new TestNG();
    testng.setTestClasses(MyTestng.class);
    testng.addListener(tla);
    testng.run();
}
```

But it just genarate only one report for one test in MyTestng.Class
I have try to change it to.

```
List<Class> lsClass = new ArrayList<Class>();
......
for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
     MyTestng test = new MyTestng (ls_test_step, ls_test_data, test_case) 
     lsClass.add(test.getClass());
}
....
Class[] arrClass = new Class[lsClass.size()];
arrClass = (Class[]) lsClass.toArray();

ITestNGListener tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
TestNG testng = new TestNG();
testng.setTestClasses(arrClass);
testng.addListener(tla);
testng.run();
```

**It cannot execute because exception:**
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Class;
    at core.App.main(App.java:101)

The problem when i just got only one class **MyTestng** but it can be executed with difference step each time it run.

Answer (score 0):

Your conversion from List to Array causes the execption. If you provide the target array you don't need to cast the result.

```
Class[] arrClass = lsClass.toArray(new Class[lsClass.size()]);
```